# .htaccess not converting the dirty url into clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

I am having an URL named `www.example.com/print?id=adder`

I want it to look like `www.example.com/print/adder`

I am using the following .htacces code

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect all requests except only POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:php?)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^print/([a-z]+) print.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But still, i am having the URL like `www.example.com/print?id=adder`.

I am using `wamp 3.0.6(Latest Version)`, `PHP 7.0,10` & `Apache 2.4.23`. Why am i facing this problem. Why isn't the code working?

Comment: is your htaccess in /print folder?

Comment: No, my .htaccess is in the root folder & print is not a folder its `print.php`. I have made the .php extensions hidden so you are seeing `print?id=` instead of `print.php?id=`

Comment: "But still, i am having the URL like ..." - you also need to change the URL in your application (this is what actually _changes_ the URL) - presumably you have already done this?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect your url to cleaner version, put this  above your last RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /print/?(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /print/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: your code changes the URL but due to that code its giving an Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: Your modified code isn't accepting @starkeen. It's converting into clean URL but its showing the same 500 Error, Internal misconfiguration error

Comment: Akshay, I dont think you are getting the error because of this rule. The rule is ok I have tested it on my server. Please check your error log for info about the 500error.